# How do I merge extruded faces with an existing face

Tags: snapping

I am modeling a head shape to make a helmet and I want to merge two faces together to fill a gap. I’m using the mirror tool on half of the face so everything is even, and on the front of the face I can just turn on clipping and extrude them together, but with the side view I can’t do that. I’m also extremely new to blender.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, and I don’t know how to delete this post.